# C++ - Is there an elegant way to read in text files?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for an elegant way to read in a text file into a 2x2 vector. I'm using this approach to write the data to a text file:

```
ofstream FILE(theFile, ios::out | ofstream::binary);
for(const auto& vt : data) {
   std::copy(vt.begin(), vt.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(FILE, " "));
   FILE << "\n\n";
 }
```

My question is, is there a way to use the `std::istream_iterator` in a similar way to be able to read in the contents of the text file?

EDIT:

Data:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > data;
```

Comment: Please show your `data` declaration . Is it vector of vector of doubles ?

Comment: One elegant (But not specially efficient) could be to read the text line by line, storing each line in a stream too, and them reading that stream to get each element of the line.

Comment: You can use a `back_inserter` and `istream_iterator` to elegantify it somewhat. Still elegance is in the eye of the beholder. Why not just do things very directly -- that way you also have more control.

Comment: _vector of vectors_ usage [is not recommended](http://upcoder.com/2/efficient-vectors-of-vectors/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you insist on using `std::istream_iterator`, this is one way

```
#include <sstream>
//....

std::vector<double> v ;
std::string str ;

while ( std::getline(FILE, str) )
{

    std::stringstream ss(str);

    std::copy( std::istream_iterator<double>(ss),
               std::istream_iterator<double>(),
               std::back_inserter(v)
             ) ;

    data.push_back( v ); // data is your vector of vector
    v.clear( );
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, won't he have to deal with the double newlines?

Comment: @Veritas probably not since `std::istream_iterator<double>()` will deal with local `stringstream` object, not with `FILE`

Comment: suggestion: turn `v` local (potentially with an initial reserved size), use move semantics when pushing to `data`, remove `v.clear()`.

Comment: @pepper_chico In fact he wouldn't even need std::copy then.
`std::stringstream ss(str);
data.push_back({std::istream_iterator<double>(ss),{}})`

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own iterator that uses a vector as the underlying type. It can be used similar to `std::istream_iterator`:

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <
    class Value,
    class Container       = std::vector<Value>,
    class charT           = char,
    class traits          = std::char_traits<charT>
>
class line_iterator
    : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, std::vector<Value>>
{
public:
    using value_type      = Value;
    using container_type  = Container;
private:
    std::basic_istream<charT, traits>*      is_;
    std::basic_string<charT, traits>        line;
    std::basic_istringstream<charT, traits> str;
    container_type                          temp;
    int                                     count = -1;
public:
    line_iterator(std::basic_istream<charT, traits>& is,
                  int count = -1) noexcept
        : is_(&is), count(count)
    { this->read(); }

    constexpr line_iterator() noexcept : is_(nullptr)
    { }

    constexpr line_iterator(const line_iterator& rhs) noexcept
        : is_(rhs.is_), temp(rhs.temp), count(rhs.count)
    { };

    constexpr container_type operator*() const noexcept
    {
        return std::move(temp);
    }

    line_iterator& operator++()
    {
        this->read();
        return *this;
    }

    line_iterator operator++(int)
    {
        line_iterator copy(*this);
        ++*this;
        return std::move(copy);
    }

    friend constexpr bool operator==(const line_iterator& lhs,
                                     const line_iterator& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return lhs.is_ == rhs.is_;
    }

    friend constexpr bool operator!=(const line_iterator& lhs,
                                     const line_iterator& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
private:
    void read()
    {
        temp.clear();

        if (is_)
        {
            if (std::getline(*is_, line))
            {
                str.str(line);

                if (count == -1)
                    temp.assign(
                    std::istream_iterator<Value, charT, traits>{str}, {});
                else if (0 <= count)
                    std::copy_n(
                        std::istream_iterator<Value, charT, traits>{str},
                        count,
                        std::back_inserter(temp));
            }

            if (!*is_)
                is_ = nullptr;

            str.clear();
        }
    }
};

template <
    class Value,
    class Container       = std::vector<Value>,
    class charT           = char,
    class traits          = std::char_traits<charT>
>
line_iterator<Value, Container, charT, traits>
constexpr line_iter(std::basic_istream<charT, traits>& is,
                    int count = -1) noexcept
{
    return line_iterator<Value, Container, charT, traits>{is, count};
}

template<class Value>
constexpr line_iterator<Value> line_iter() noexcept
{
    return line_iterator<Value>{};
}
```

Now you can initialize the vector with:

```c++
std::vector<std::vector<double>> v{line_iter<double>(FILE), line_iter<double>()};
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fb6dbc32530506c2)</kbd>